# rename the java plugins and features during maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, tycho

I have most of my bundle names with convention **com.orgName.productName.moduleName.subModuleName.abc** and ***few*** correspondong feature names as **com.orgName.productName.feature.moduleName.subModuleName.abc**.

Now due to some major agreements, we have to rename a part of plugin name, say rename **.orgName.productName.** for all the bundles with something like **org.open.**

This seems to be a major refactoring. I have atleast 50 bundles and huge test suite dependencies, my CI builds on these plugin names.

We thought we just change the name of the bundle's and feature's packaging jar file during the maven build. This helps us avoiding this refactoring work.So can i do something like this?

Will the copy-rename-maven-plugin help me.?
Please suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The names of feature and bundle artifacts are also repeated in the content of the artifacts (MANIFEST.MF, feature.xml), so only changing the JAR names will not work.

Comment: Yes, i have to change everywhere it occurs, in all the files. Can this be accomplished? please suggest.